# MongoDB get data from other day, timezone

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Since I'm in Mexico City, I'm currently getting the data from the next day until 6 am, since Mexico City is in Central Time Zone which is UTC-06:00. How can I get the data from the next day until 6am? As in the image, I just want to get the data from week 20, which includes data from week 21 until 6 am of that monday. Thank you. Please help

Aggregation:

```
[{
    $match: {
       start_date: {
          $gte: ISODate('2020-05-18T00:00:01'),
          $lte: ISODate('2020-05-24T23:59:59')
       }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
       week: {
         "$cond": {
           "if": {"$eq": [{"$dayOfWeek": '$start_date'}, 1]},
           "then": {"$subtract": [{"$week": '$start_date'}, 1]},
           "else": {"$week": '$start_date'}
         }
       },
       solved: '$solved',
       survey: '$survey'
    }
}, {
    $group: {
       _id: '$week',
       count: {
          $sum: 1
       }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
       _id: 1
    }
}]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You need to figure out the window in your application and translate it to UTC. MongoDB does not have timezone support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB always stores the data in UTC format. So suppose you store some data in database it will store in the database by subtracting `-6` from the current Mexico time. So now how do you get that data from the database?

The answer is, If you need to extract the data from the database you actually need to pass the date from the frontend since backend does not know your actual timezone.

Frontend:-

```
const startDate = moment().startOf("day").toISOString()
const endDate = moment().endOf("day").toISOString()
```

Backend:-

```
const { startDate, endDate } = request.query;

{
    $match: {
       start_date: {
          $gte: moment(startDate).toDate(),
          $lte: moment(endDate).toDate()
       }
    }
}
```